# Populate combo box with distinct values from one table based on values existing in another?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to populate a combo box with distinct values pulled from a clients table, but only if those clients exist in the mfgOrders table.  I have set the Row Source to the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client.ClientName FROM Client 
INNER JOIN mfgOrders ON Client.id=mfgOrders.client;
```

When I switch to Datasheet view, I can see all the distinct clients that are also in the mfgOrders table.  The problem is that this does not populate in the combo box.

I originally thought that this may be due to the data size, but oddly enough when I select ClientName from Client, it will populate the box successfully but with ALL clients.

Unfortunately, I don't want all clients in the combo box.  Just the clients which also appear in the mfgOrders table.

I'm stumped on this one.  Is my logic incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried to do this manually via VBA?

Comment: With the form open, what do you get from this in the Immediate window?  `Debug.Print Forms!YourFormName!YourComboName.ListCount`

Comment: Novice miscellaneous question:  What's an easy method of adding a debug line to VBA in an MS Office application?  I've been creating a button on the form that runs that code when pressed whenever I need to debug.  But, there must be an easier way.

Comment: I meant open the Immediate window, then type `Debug.Print Forms!YourFormName!YourComboName.ListCount` and press Enter.

Comment: Sorry to be asking dumb questions, but I don't know how to get to a console window to type that command Hans.  To answer you question, I populated a MsgBox when I pressed a button.  The result is 58, the same number of records pulled into the Datasheet view.

Comment: OK, that works.  Thanks.  Your combo is being populated correctly, but the contents are not visible.  But why?  Check the property sheet for the combo: column count; bound column; column width; visible and enabled; foreground  and background colors ... it's gotta be something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Use CTRL+g to open the Immediate window.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I never knew about the Immediate Window.  That should make debugging much quicker!  Also, I figured out the error.  For whatever reason the column count was set to 2, and widths were 0";2".  I didn't think that the order of my query would matter, but I guess it does as I have a hidden field before the returned value.

Comment: Could you please copy/paste that solution as an answer so I can check it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when linking a drop-down list to a query, the list will be populated based on how many fields are queried.

In this case, despite the first field being used simply to create the union, Access created a combo box with 2 columns, the first of which had a width of 0".

This appears to have been done because the "show" box for the first field in the query was unchecked.  The result was a blank list.

To fix the error I simply re-arranged the query.